# Accepting any ERC20 Token as a payment within smart contract

Tags: solidity, erc20

[This is the contract I have written which contains addLiquidity whose job is to simply transfer token from my wallet to smart contract.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2wfe.png)

[This is the javascript code I have written so that I can approve the smart contract to accept ERC20 token.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sawtl.png)

[This is the error ie appearing when I am running the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR8WR.png)

I just want to send ERC20 token from my wallet to smart contract. Why I want to do this is because I want to create a pool of tokens on the smart contract which I would use for some new kind of swapping which I have thought of. But for all this to happen tokens need to go from user's wallet to smart contract. PLease tell me where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Before using `transferFrom()`, the user needs to `approve()` your contract address as the spender.

They need to do it in a separate transaction to the `token2` contract, not through your contract.

In other words - the user needs to send two transactions. First one to `token.approve(yourContract, amount)`, and the second one to `yourContract.addLiquidity()`.

Comment: `IERC20(token2).approve(
            address(this),
            amount2
        );

        IERC20(token2).transferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amount2
        ); `

Comment: I added the approve line within the addLiquidity function. So first it must approve the contract to withdraw upto amount2 from msg.sender wallet. Now when I compiled it and tried to rerun it, again gives the same error that gas estimation is not possible.

Comment: Can you please guide where am I going wrong now ?

Comment: @yashmathur The user needs to execute the `approve()` function directly on the token contract - not through your contract. So there's effectively two transactions - one to the token contract (invoking `approve()`), and other to your contract.

Comment: please check the edits on the post

Comment: please check the edited post. I have attached photos of what I have done. Please tell me where am I going wrong

Comment: @yashmathur The edit has changed the question meaning, and made it not reproducible anymore. Please post a separate question with a minimal reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: Thank You for your help it's sorted. As you said I approved from the client side. The only mistake I did was that I did not wait for the transaction to complete after I called the approve function and immediately called the liquidity function. Due to this although there was no permission yet I was trying to use transferFrom method which ultimately produced error.